# What is the difference between turtle size, patch size and frame rate in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want to know the Relationship between turtle size and patch size in Netlogo. Also I want to make those sizes in a way such that any turtle moves from one patch to another at every tick.

Answer (score 2):

- Patch size is measured in pixels. It is configurable in the "Model Settings" dialog.
- You can think of turtle size as measured in "patches". A turtle of size 1 should appear to be the size of one patch. (Note, however, that turtle size is a "display only" property. Conceptually, turtles are just points. They don't really occupy space in the NetLogo world even if they appear to do so.)
- Changing the `xcor` or the `ycor` of a turtle by 1 should move it by exactly one patch. If you want them to move diagonally, things are a bit more messy. You might be better off targeting destination patches directly, e.g.:

```
; move to the patch north-east of current position:
ask one-of turtles [ move-to patch-at 1 1 ]
; move to an adjacent patch at random:
ask one-of turtles [ move-to one-of neighbors ]
```

Those are just examples, of course. The code to use will depend on what exactly you are trying to do. If you tell us more in a separate question, we might be able to help you.